# Wordpress admin screen has no checkboxes for any options

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, admin

I am currently building a custom theme locally using WordPress. I noticed recently when I logged into wp-admin that the options that should have checkboxes do not have any. This includes anywhere in wp-admin that should have a checkbox, such as the screen options pull down at the top or any options in the plugins I have installed. I believe that the checkbox functionality is still there, but there is just no visual indicator. Anyone encounter anything similar before. I can't recall when this first started happening, but the last plugin I installed was WooCommerce if that had anything to do with it. I have tried disabling it, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the Wordpress Core, it seems to be related to the core . Also enable debug mode in your wp-config.php file by adding this line: define('WP_DEBUG', true);. This will show errors and may tell you what the problem is.